# LaunchImage issue on iPhone6

Tags: ios, iphone-6, launchimage

I am facing an issue in setting the launch image for iPhone 6 and 6 plus. I have created a launch image of size 750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait and named it as Default-667h@2x.png.
I copied the file the resources folder of the project. When I run the project on iPhone 6, the launch image shows up but is replaced by Default@2x.png before going to landing screen.
The app works fine on other devices. I am using IBM worklight.
Is there something else needs to be done.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668970/iphone-6-6-screen-size-issue/26859670#26859670

Answer (score 0):

You will first need to update your installation to the latest available. This is based on the following APAR: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI26896

After doing the above, you can then follow the instructions in the APAR body, or the ones in Samir's link in the comments.