# iPhone 6/6+ Screen size issue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, iphone-6, iphone-6-plus

This is driving me crazy. After doing the necessary things, on iPhone 6 simulator, I am getting correct `self.view.bounds {{0, 0}, {375, 667}}` but on the actual iPhone 6 device it is still showing `{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}`. Here is what I tried :

1. Updated Images.xcassets to include launch images for all devices starting from 6+ down to iPhone 4,
2. Updated @3x icon (180x180) in Images.xcassets,
3. Even tried a xib as launch file (XCode -> File -> New -> File -> Launch Screen),

But all in vain on actual iPhone 6 device, though it works on simulator. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. The issue was I was using Zoomed display on iPhone 6. I set it back to standard and the bounds were correct.

Comment: me too...... I just set display Zoomed mode , the iphone6plus goto iphone6 bound size....so poor...

Answer (score 0):

When the system launches an app for the first time on a device, it temporarily displays a static launch image on the screen. This image is your app’s launch image and it is a resource that you specify in your Xcode project. Launch images provide the user with immediate feedback that your app has launched while giving your app time to prepare its initial user interface. When your app’s window is configured and ready to be displayed, the system swaps out the launch image for that window.

When a recent snapshot of your app’s user interface is available, the system prefers the use of that image over the use of your app’s launch images. The system takes a snapshot of your app’s user interface when your app transitions from the foreground to the background. When your app returns to the foreground, it uses that image instead of a launch image whenever possible. In cases where the user has killed your app or your app has not run for a long time, the system discards the snapshot and relies once again on your launch images.

New Xcode projects include image asset entries for your app’s launch images. To add launch images, add the corresponding image files to the image assets of your project. At build time, Xcode adds the appropriate keys to your app’s Info.plist file and places the images in your app bundle.

For iPhone 6:

```
750 x 1334 (@2x) for portrait

1334 x 750 (@2x) for landscape
```

For iPhone 6 Plus:

```
1242 x 2208 (@3x) for portrait

2208 x 1242 (@3x) for landscape
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH22-SW1

Here are relevant bits of your Info.plist:

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 480}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-568h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{320, 568}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-667h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{375, 667}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-736h</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{414, 736}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Portrait</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>8.0</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
        <string>Default-Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
        <string>Landscape</string>
        <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
        <string>{768, 1024}</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```